# CSS Transition with Radio Button and JS

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

With my jQuery code I am able to get the attributes from the .item but my css transitions aren't working. You can see the intended transition by replacing `.item` with `.item-tile`.

How do get my CSS transitions to work with my `jQuery` code?

```js
$(".item-wrap").on("click", ".item", function() {
  var itemColor = $(this)
    .find(".icon")
    .css("background-color");
  $(".category-color").css("background-color", itemColor);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.item-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item-wrap .item {
  position: relative;
}

.item-wrap .item .radio-button {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-wrap .item .item-tile {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease, -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
}

.item-wrap .item .radio-button:checked+.item-tile {
  border: 2px solid #079ad9;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.category-color {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">
      <input id="clothing" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:blue;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input id="elephant" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:red;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <input id="fish" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
        <div class="item-tile">
          <div class="icon" style="background-color:green;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="copy-container">
    <div class="category-color">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: *"The noise generated from all the text surrounding the error prevents future users from relating your question and the answer to their own issue. It also makes it much harder for anyone to determine what the problem is. That makes your question less likely to get an answer and wastes the time of anyone who tries to help you. The question is effectively only useful to you, is less likely to get answered and offers little or no value whatsoever to the community as a whole."*

Comment: I have now edited the original and stripped it to the bare minimum to demonstrate the issue for future references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:focus` instead of `:checked`.

**Why?**

Simply because on your jQuery code you are returning false and preventing the default behvavior of the radio input so **it cannot be checked**.

```js
$(".item-wrap").on("click", ".item", function() {
  $("#text-preview").text($(this).find(".item-text").text());
  var path = $(this)
    .find("#item-path")
    .attr("d");
  var pathb = $(this)
    .find("#item-path")
    .attr("d");
  var pathc = $(this)
    .find("#item-path")
    .attr("d");
  $("#path-preview").attr("d", path);
  $("#path-preview").attr("d", pathb);
  $("#path-preview").attr("d", pathc);
  var itemColor = $(this)
    .find(".icon")
    .css("background-color");
  $(".category-color").css("background-color", itemColor);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.item-wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.item-tile {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 3px -1px rgba(245, 245, 245, 1);
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 3px -1px rgba(245, 245, 245, 1);
}

.item-tile label {
  flex: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.icon {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item-wrap .item {
  position: relative;
}

.item-wrap .item .radio-button {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-wrap .item .item-tile {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease, -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
}

.item-wrap .item .icon svg {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

.item-wrap .item .radio-button:focus+.item-tile {
  border: 2px solid #079ad9;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">
      <input id="clothing" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:blue;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" viewBox="0 0 35 35" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
<g fill="#fff" stroke="#fff">
  <path id="item-path" d="M21.435 15.78c-2.34-1.886-5.302-2.878-8.303-3.002v-1.022c1.036-.28 1.8-1.227 1.8-2.35 0-1.342-1.09-2.433-2.432-2.433-1.342 0-2.434 1.09-2.434 2.433 0 .35.284.632.632.632.35 0 .632-.283.632-.632 0-.645.525-1.17 1.17-1.17.645 0 1.17.525 1.17 1.17 0 .645-.525 1.17-1.17 1.17-.348 0-.632.282-.632.63v1.572c-3 .124-5.962 1.116-8.303 3-.543.44-.63 1.234-.19 1.778.436.543 1.232.63 1.775.19 4.053-3.262 10.647-3.262 14.7 0 .233.19.513.28.79.28.37 0 .737-.16.986-.47.438-.544.352-1.34-.19-1.777z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
        </div>
        <label for="clothing" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Clothing</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input id="elephant" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:red;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
<g fill="#fff" stroke="#fff">
  <path id="item-path" d="M19.565 9.34H15.48c-.146 1.18-.736 2.262-1.67 3.028-.09.072-.196.108-.303.108-.138 0-.276-.06-.37-.175-.168-.203-.138-.505.066-.673.86-.705 1.354-1.747 1.354-2.858 0-2.04-1.657-3.696-3.695-3.696-1.906 0-3.48 1.45-3.674 3.306-.236.137-.456.3-.654.488-.073.07-.14.14-.206.214-.826.936-1.008 2.16-1.008 3.053 0 .382.01.765.02 1.135.03 1.11.066 2.493-.3 2.87-.03.03-.115.117-.422.117-.53 0-.957.43-.957.957 0 .53.43.957.958.957.74 0 1.343-.233 1.793-.695.602-.617.796-1.505.847-2.513.113.003.234.005.36.005.955 0 2.245-.115 3.266-.627 0 0-.07.442-.07.568v3.807c0 .68.643 1.21 1.325 1.21h.018c.682 0 1.23-.53 1.23-1.21v-1.958h4.544v1.974c0 .673.565 1.196 1.237 1.196h.018c.672 0 1.197-.523 1.197-1.195v-2.18c.598-.3.957-.9.957-1.587v-3.828c0-.99-.784-1.794-1.775-1.794zM7.19 12.108c0-.25.2-.45.45-.45s.45.2.45.45-.2.45-.45.45-.45-.2-.45-.45z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
        </div>
        <label for="elephant" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Elephant</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input id="fish" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:green;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
<g fill="#fff" stroke="#fff">
  <path id="item-path" d="M13.587 16.6h1.83c-.255 1.303-1.406 2.31-2.773 2.31-1.558 0-2.823-1.278-2.823-2.836v-5.166c.15-.145.25-.365.25-.61V5.883c0-.438-.337-.793-.775-.793s-.776.356-.776.794v4.413c0 .246.1.466.25.61v5.167c0 2.115 1.738 3.835 3.853 3.835 2.09 0 3.82-1.718 3.846-3.832l.01-1.968v-1.574L13.588 16.6z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
        </div>
        <label for="fish" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Fish</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copy-container">
  <div class="copy-svg category-color">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
<g fill="#fff" stroke="">
  <path id="path-preview" d=""/>
  </g>
</svg>
  </div>
  <text id="text-preview"></text>
</div>
```

---

By the way i don't see the utility of this `return false` so if you remove it your code will work fine:

```js
$(".item-wrap").on("click", ".item", function() {
  $("#text-preview").text($(this).find(".item-text").text());
  var path = $(this)
    .find("#item-path")
    .attr("d");
  var pathb = $(this)
    .find("#item-path")
    .attr("d");
  var pathc = $(this)
    .find("#item-path")
    .attr("d");
  $("#path-preview").attr("d", path);
  $("#path-preview").attr("d", pathb);
  $("#path-preview").attr("d", pathc);
  var itemColor = $(this)
    .find(".icon")
    .css("background-color");
  $(".category-color").css("background-color", itemColor);
});
```

```css
.item-wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.item-tile {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 3px -1px rgba(245, 245, 245, 1);
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 3px -1px rgba(245, 245, 245, 1);
}

.item-tile label {
  flex: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.icon {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item-wrap .item {
  position: relative;
}

.item-wrap .item .radio-button {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-wrap .item .item-tile {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease, -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
}

.item-wrap .item .icon svg {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

.item-wrap .item .radio-button:checked+.item-tile {
  border: 2px solid #079ad9;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">
      <input id="clothing" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:blue;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" viewBox="0 0 35 35" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
<g fill="#fff" stroke="#fff">
  <path id="item-path" d="M21.435 15.78c-2.34-1.886-5.302-2.878-8.303-3.002v-1.022c1.036-.28 1.8-1.227 1.8-2.35 0-1.342-1.09-2.433-2.432-2.433-1.342 0-2.434 1.09-2.434 2.433 0 .35.284.632.632.632.35 0 .632-.283.632-.632 0-.645.525-1.17 1.17-1.17.645 0 1.17.525 1.17 1.17 0 .645-.525 1.17-1.17 1.17-.348 0-.632.282-.632.63v1.572c-3 .124-5.962 1.116-8.303 3-.543.44-.63 1.234-.19 1.778.436.543 1.232.63 1.775.19 4.053-3.262 10.647-3.262 14.7 0 .233.19.513.28.79.28.37 0 .737-.16.986-.47.438-.544.352-1.34-.19-1.777z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
        </div>
        <label for="clothing" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Clothing</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input id="elephant" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:red;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
<g fill="#fff" stroke="#fff">
  <path id="item-path" d="M19.565 9.34H15.48c-.146 1.18-.736 2.262-1.67 3.028-.09.072-.196.108-.303.108-.138 0-.276-.06-.37-.175-.168-.203-.138-.505.066-.673.86-.705 1.354-1.747 1.354-2.858 0-2.04-1.657-3.696-3.695-3.696-1.906 0-3.48 1.45-3.674 3.306-.236.137-.456.3-.654.488-.073.07-.14.14-.206.214-.826.936-1.008 2.16-1.008 3.053 0 .382.01.765.02 1.135.03 1.11.066 2.493-.3 2.87-.03.03-.115.117-.422.117-.53 0-.957.43-.957.957 0 .53.43.957.958.957.74 0 1.343-.233 1.793-.695.602-.617.796-1.505.847-2.513.113.003.234.005.36.005.955 0 2.245-.115 3.266-.627 0 0-.07.442-.07.568v3.807c0 .68.643 1.21 1.325 1.21h.018c.682 0 1.23-.53 1.23-1.21v-1.958h4.544v1.974c0 .673.565 1.196 1.237 1.196h.018c.672 0 1.197-.523 1.197-1.195v-2.18c.598-.3.957-.9.957-1.587v-3.828c0-.99-.784-1.794-1.775-1.794zM7.19 12.108c0-.25.2-.45.45-.45s.45.2.45.45-.2.45-.45.45-.45-.2-.45-.45z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
        </div>
        <label for="elephant" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Elephant</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input id="fish" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:green;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
<g fill="#fff" stroke="#fff">
  <path id="item-path" d="M13.587 16.6h1.83c-.255 1.303-1.406 2.31-2.773 2.31-1.558 0-2.823-1.278-2.823-2.836v-5.166c.15-.145.25-.365.25-.61V5.883c0-.438-.337-.793-.775-.793s-.776.356-.776.794v4.413c0 .246.1.466.25.61v5.167c0 2.115 1.738 3.835 3.853 3.835 2.09 0 3.82-1.718 3.846-3.832l.01-1.968v-1.574L13.588 16.6z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
        </div>
        <label for="fish" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Fish</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copy-container">
  <div class="copy-svg category-color">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
<g fill="#fff" stroke="">
  <path id="path-preview" d=""/>
  </g>
</svg>
  </div>
  <text id="text-preview"></text>
</div>
```